# Finding a normal subgroup $H$ of $\mathbb{Z}_{mn}$ of order $m$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Find a normal subgroup $H$ of $\mathbb{Z}_{mn}$ of order $m$ where $m$ and $n$ are positive integers. Show that $H$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{m}$.

I am honestly not even sure where to start. My initial thoughts were if $\mathbb{Z}_{mn}$ was isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{m}\times \mathbb{Z}_{n}$ then I could find a subgroup $H$ from that group. However, I discovered that $\mathbb{Z}_{mn}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{m}\times \mathbb{Z}_{n}$ but the converse is not true. 
Would $H$ look like a cyclic group of order $m$ with an arbitrary generator $a$?

Any help would be great.

Comment: Suppose $x$ is a generator for $\Bbb Z_{mn}$. What can you say about the order of $nx$ (Here, $nx = x + x + \cdots + x$ ($n$ times))?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathbb Z_{mn}$ is cyclic has an element of order $mn$ say $x$ Then $nx$ has order $m$.Let $H=\langle nx\rangle $

Now use any two finite cyclic groups are isomorphic

Comment: I apologize for not being clear but the end goal is to use the _fundamental homomorphism theorem_ or the _first isomorphism theorem_. So it would be a better idea to construct a function that is a bijective homomorphism. However, I do not know how to construct such a function for this case.

Comment: It looks like I'm just working with numbers mod _mn_ here. So if I put _x=1_ and think about the set of numbers _{0,n,2n,3n,...,(m-1)n}_. I can see a correspondence with _{0,1,2,3,...,(m-1)}_ but do not know how to make the function.